# Partitioning Spatial Dependence?

Tags: spatial, partitioning, local-statistics

So, I have a group of nations that exhibit global spatial dependence. I want to partition the nations into groups so that, at an intuitive level at least, the "sum of the spatial dependence within each group" or some similar measure is maximized. This problem seems similar to local statistics, but I'm not looking for "hot spots"; I want to partition all the nations. It also seems similar to spatial regimes, but its an issue of dependence, not heterogeneity.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Reminds me a bit of Aldstadt and Getis ([2006](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1538-4632.2006.00689.x)). The popular measures of spatial dependence have local analogues (Moran's I and Geary's C), so viz. and clustering those local values into groups (where you do the clustering to your fancy) may be sufficient for what you want.

Comment: That's a helpful reference. It's also similar to the seeded region growing that is referenced. Neither are exactly what I'm looking for but I think I can try and modify them.